# What's an efficient way to shift a range of items left or right within an 1d NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.7

Suppose I have an array like so:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I'd like to shift a given range of items left or right. So for example, shifting right by 3 positions, starting from position 4:

```
>>> shift(arr, 4, 3)
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

or shifting starting from position 4, but to the left:

```
>>> shift(arr, 4, -3)
arr = [0, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]
```

I left the original items in place but it doesn't matter whats stays in the original position where that range of items was located at. Could be zeroes or anything else - I'll override that anyways.

I'm pretty new to NumPy but I am thinking there may be some slicing syntax to accomplish this with NumPy, but I am having trouble coming up with how to accomplish this.

The alternative would be to do a loop and just copy the items one by one but I'm hoping there is a more efficient / elegant way to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what happens with elements that are shifted out of the array bounds?

Comment: Yeah, you can use basic slicing for this, it just does the "alternative" loop in C code instead. You have to do a bit of math to figure out what indices you're using to write and what indices you want to overwrite, and in this case they do have to be the same length. In general, assigning an array to a basic slice of another array require compatible shapes for broadcasting (look this up, it'll really help).

Comment: @Marat it won't - I am operating over a large array that is guaranteed to be large enough to accommodate the shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the portion of the array you are going to shift (from `position` to the end of the array less the shift amount (if it's positive)) and then replace the portion of the array from the new position (`position + shift`) with that extracted piece. This will leave the original values in place.

```
def shift(arr, pos, amt):
    arrv = arr[pos:min(len(arr)-amt, len(arr))]
    arr[pos+amt:pos+amt+len(arrv)] = arrv
    
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

shift(arr, 4, 3)
print(arr)
shift(arr, 4, -3)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to come p with and your answer actually helped me understand how slicing works in python.